# XMLHttpRequest response has no headers in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, extjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm making an XMLHttpRequest using ExtJS to a service that returns no responseText, just a 204 and the response header *TotalNearby*. The call works perfectly using Firefox, but with Internet Explorer 8, both alert boxes are empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'services/getNearby',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        'lat': 34,
        'lon': -90
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': AUTH_TOKEN
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.status == 204) {
            alert(response.getAllResponseHeaders());
            alert(response.getResponseHeader('Total-Nearby'));
        }
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert('Server status ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the site http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/bugs.asp this is an IE 7/8 bug:

> IE0013: IE XMLHTTP implementation
>   turns 204 response code into bogus
>   1223 status code
>
> Described here
>   http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1450, the
>   XMLHTTPRequest object in IE will
>   return a status code of 1223 and drop
>   all response headers if the server
>   returns a HTTP/204 No Content
>   response.
>
> This is caused by an internal design
>   artifact of URLMon (binding returns
>   Operation Aborted (1223) if the server
>   returns no content in response to a
>   request).
>
> Repros in IE8, IE7 (and probably
>   earlier).
>
> Workaround: Treat "1223" as equivalent
>   to a 204.  Note: HTTP headers remain
>   unavailable in this case.

If you are seeing empty alerts, meaning IE did not change the status code to 1223, then that part of the bug may have been fixed.  However, I would be more worried about the statement:

> Note: HTTP headers remain unavailable in this case.

as this appears to be the problem you're facing.  Do you need to use a service that does not respond with content? You might be better suited to return a typical response with a message body.

Comment: Luckily I can alter the service. Thanks!

Comment: 204 is a typical status code as defined by the rfc specification.

Comment: @user2524908 Where in my answer did I imply that a 204 isn't a proper status code defined by the specification? This is an issue with IE 7/8 not handling ajax 204s correctly, as stated in my answer above.